# Codeigniter - blank page on fresh xampp installation

Tags: codeigniter, xampp

I have weird problem. I have to modify old CodeIgniter project.

Im using local windows XAMPP server for development, and my project was working on XAMPP.

Few weeks ago I reinstalled operating system . I installed XAMPP (same version) and i moved htdocs from default `c:\xampp\htdocs` to `e:\htdocs`. I had no problems with XAMPP with moved htdocs (other non-codeigniter projects are working fine).

Today I copied application from production server to my localhost and it's not working.

When I try to open in browser: `http://localhost/myprojectfolder` im getting blank page.

Clean CodeIgniter installation on local windows XAMPP works (however clean installation is not using .htaccess).

Project is working normally on production web server with .htaccess file like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /myprojectfolder

    ### Canonicalize codeigniter URLs

    # If your default controller is something other than
    # "welcome" you should probably change this
    # RewriteRule ^(welcome(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]
    # RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]

    # Removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

    # Removes access to the system folder by users.
    # Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    # previously this would not have been possible.
    # 'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

    # Without mod_rewrite, route 404's to the front controller
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

</IfModule>
```

I dont remember, that i had separate .htaccess file for localhost or not. If I had - it was overwritten by file from production server.

MySQL database used in project is identical on both servers (name, user, password, structure etc.).

My `$config['uri_protocol']` is set to `AUTO` and it was working on XAMPP with `AUTO`.

My file permissions in `htdocs` are fine (user that is starting httpd.exe service can read and write there).

My routing:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['admin'] = 'admin/start';
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

Any ideas?

Comment: this is due to routing, change routing and see.

Comment: change $config['uri_protocol'] with other parameters one by one and see.

Comment: @MDeSilva change routing... how?

Comment: @MDeSilva changing uri_protocol to every possible option not helped.